# Can not convert a string to proper date format

Tags: java, date

In my HTML part I have text box where the date is entered as: `10.09.2013 (dd.mm.yyyy)`

What I'm doing in my servlet is:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
                String dateInString = invoiceData.getString("date");            
                Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
                System.out.println(date);
```

The system prints: `Thu Jan 10 00:09:00 EET 2013` and inside of the `oracle` database it's inserted as `10-SEP-2013`

Please help me! I'm dealing with it for about 2 hours and I really can not find a way to convert it and insert it correctly in my database. I know that I'm missing something super small, but I'm unable to spot it.

I'm using `Jboss 7.1` server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm is used for **minutes** and MM is used for **Month**

SO you need to change:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

instead of

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
```

mm stands for Minutes. MM stands for Month

Take a look [date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

mm stands for minutes.
You need to use MM in your pattern to get the month.

Answer (score 1):

`mm` for Minutes and `MM` for Month. Change the format to `dd.MM.yyyy` get the correct date.
Change your code like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                String dateInString = invoiceData.getString("date");            
                Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
                System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

use following format

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```